# Import less file from the node_modules

Tags: import, less

I'm looking the simpliest way to import less files with the **~alias** from a **node_modules** like less loader in webpack.

```
FileError: '~@folder/composant/file.less' wasn't found
```

It seems that less 2.7 can't understand this. Since I don't need webpack here, is there any solution here?

Comment: if you add the braces for intepolation `'~@{folder}/composant/file.less';` is working? Or you problem is directly that alias is not recognized?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, since version 3 Less itself is capable of resolving imports from node modules, if executed in a node environment:

`@import '@scope/package/composant/file.less'`